# How to transfer a scanned image from WIA ImageFile to TBitmap without saving it to disk?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, wia

I'm using this code to acquire the scanned image from WIA:

```
const
  wiaFormatJPEG = '{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}';
  wiaFormatPNG = '{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}';
var
  CommonDialog: ICommonDialog;
  AImage: IImageFile;
  i: Integer;
begin
  CommonDialog := CreateOleObject('WIA.CommonDialog') as ICommonDialog;

  for i := 1 to Scanner.Properties.Count do
  begin
    if (Scanner.Properties[i].Name = 'Horizontal Resolution') or
      (Scanner.Properties[i].Name = 'Vertical Resolution') then
      Scanner.Properties[i].Set_Value(72)
    else if Scanner.Properties[i].Name = 'Horizontal Extent' then
      Scanner.Properties[i].Set_Value(Round(8.27 * 72))
    else if Scanner.Properties[i].Name = 'Vertical Extent' then
      Scanner.Properties[i].Set_Value(Round(11.00 * 72));
  end;
  AImage := IUnknown(CommonDialog.ShowTransfer(Scanner, wiaFormatPNG, True)) as IImageFile;
  //Save the image
  AImage.SaveFile('D:\1.' + AImage.FileExtension);
  imgImage.Picture.LoadFromFile('D:\1.' + AImage.FileExtension);
  DeleteFile('D:\1.' + AImage.FileExtension);
end;
```

`Scanner` is initialized using this code:

```
Scanner := DevMgr.DeviceInfos[Integer(cbWIASource.Items.Objects[cbWIASource.ItemIndex])].Connect.Items[1];
```

And `DevMgr` and `cbWIASource` are initialized using this code:

```
DevMgr := CreateOleObject('WIA.DeviceManager') as IDeviceManager;
for i := 1 to DevMgr.DeviceInfos.Count do
    for j := 1 to DevMgr.DeviceInfos[i].Properties.Count do
      if DevMgr.DeviceInfos[i].Properties[j].Name = 'Name' then
      begin
        cbWIASource.Items.AddObject(DevMgr.DeviceInfos[i].Properties[j].Get_Value, TObject(i));
        Break;
      end;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to copy the scanned document without first saving it to the disk. I read on MSDN that I can access `ARGBData` member of `ImageFile` to access pixel data, but is there a simple way to copy the entire image from `FileData` to `TBitmap`? For instance, can I use a `TMemoryStream`?

---

Just as an update, I found [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SharedSample001) on MSDN. I know nothing about VB, but I guess the `Picture` object is a wrapper around `HBITMAP`. So, is it logical to conclude that the `ImageFile.Picture` property is what I need?

Comment: What is `IImageFile` really called? Websearch has not heard of it.

Comment: @David, this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630506(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: OK, so it's real name is `ImageFile`.

Comment: Create a `TBitmap` with 32bpp pixel format. Then use the `ScanLine` property of the bitmap to transfer across the pixel data from `ARGBData`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Isn't it possible to use either `FileData.BinaryData` or `ARGBData.BinaryData` and copy it to a `TMemoryStream` instead? I have a bad feeling about running for loops on a 20000x20000 pixel image.

Comment: You would not need any for loops. Just blit the entire contents on to the first scanline. I suspect that the format of `FileData` varies whereas `ARGBData` is always 32bpp.

Comment: @David, I don't think it's enough. The [`ARGBData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630563(v=vs.85).aspx) property returns a collection of bytes in order of ARGB whilst 32-bit Delphi bitmap uses BGRA order.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm using this code, (BA is `array of Byte`) and I'm getting an exception with this message: " The Vector's Type is not compatible with this operation." Could you please give me a few hints? `  BMP := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    BMP.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    BMP.Width := AImage.Width;
    BMP.Height := AImage.Height;
    BA := BMP.ScanLine[0];
    SetLength(BA, AImage.ARGBData.Count);
    BA := AImage.ARGBData.Get_BinaryData;
    imgImage.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(BMP);
  finally
    BMP.Free;
  end;
`

Comment: @TLama Are you sure? That sounds like an endian thing. The Delphi bitmap isn't really a Delphi object. It's the Windows HBITMAP.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I suspect the `ImageFile.ARGBData` isn't compatible with `HBITMAP`

Comment: I know nothing about ImageFile. Sorry. If you want help I'd suggest fixing the question to use the correct name for this thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IImageFile has a property FileData with provides access to the binary image data, via [IVector.BinaryData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)